# Pack two ASCII bytes into a ushort

Tags: c#, .net

I need to be able to pack two ASCII bytes into one ushort. How can I accomplish this?

So far I have:

```
for (var i = 0; i < asciiBytes.Length; i += 2)
{
    // Get two bytes from an ASCII byte array.
    var sub = new[] { asciiBytes[i], asciiBytes[i + 1] }; 

    // Pack the two bytes into a ushort
    // ????????
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [left-shift operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx) to shift your first byte 8 bits left, and then use [bitwise OR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx) to combine it with the second byte.

```
ushort x = (ushort)((asciiBytes[i] << 8) | asciiBytes[i + 1]);
```

This is arithmetically equivalent to (but more efficient than):

```
ushort x = (ushort)(asciiBytes[i] * 256 + asciiBytes[i + 1]);
```

**Edit**: The reverse operation is:

```
byte b1 = (byte)(x >> 8);
byte b2 = (byte)(x & 255);
```

Comment: And maybe the 2 bytes should be swapped, depends on actual requirements.

Comment: Thanks!  How would I parse the two bytes out later?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel here?  `BitConverter` is far more maintainable for this...

Comment: @ReedCopsey: I agree, although I prefer the manual approach for the reverse operation since it avoids allocating a `byte[]` (which is a reference type and needs to be garbage-collected) for each value.

Answer (score 2):

The [BitConverter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.BitConverter.aspx) provides methods for converting from `byte[]` to and from many standard types, including `ushort`.  You can use [BitConverter.ToUInt16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint16.aspx) to handle this directly.

```
ushort value = BitConverter.ToUInt16(asciiBytes, i); // Can pass the index directly

// To "unpack":
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
```

Note that this uses the system's byte order, which can be determined by [BitConverter.IsLittleEndian](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx).

Comment: BitConverter is good in principle, but IMO the implementation was borked. Not being able to control endianness was one pain point. Another was the APIs that return new byte-arrays rather than taking a byte-array and offset as parameters. A shame, really.

Comment: @MarcGravell Good for converting to primitives - not so great for going back into arrays.